# Como guardar datos dinámicos de un table

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-8

Hola con todos necesito una ayuda o guía respecto a como poder realizar un guardado de datos de un table el cual se carga de forma dinamica mediante una consulta, dicho table adicialmente tiene checkbox y select los cuales el usuario tenga que seleccionar y guardar esos datos en una tabla en mi bd e aqui mi duda de como poder hacerlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es mi table el cual se carga los datos de mi bd pero los checkbox select e input salen vacío para que el usuario llene.

Lo que busco es poder guardar los datos de esta forma por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde cada Id_instalacion corresponde al checkbox practicamente cada row a guardar dependera de lo que el usuario escoja y llene.

Actualmente mi controlador es este:

```
 $soft_instal = new Software_instalacion;
        $soft_instal->id_instalacion          = $instalaciones->id;
        $soft_instal->id_historial            = $historial->id;
        $soft_instal->id_software_instalacion = $value;
        $soft_instal->id_usuario              = $request->id_usuario;
        $soft_instal->id_tipo_venta           = $request->id_tipo_venta;
        $soft_instal->obs_software            = $request->obs_software ;
        $soft_instal->prueba                  = $request->prueba ;
        $soft_instal->save();
```

Y mi view es este:

```
    <form  action="{{route('instalaciones.store')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf

            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Datos generales</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 col-xxl-6 mb-3">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <input name="nombre" id="nombre" class=" form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 col-xxl-6 mb-3">
                        <label>Clientes: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente">
                                <option>Seleccionar</option>
                                @foreach ($clientes as $cli)
                                    <option value="{{ $cli->id }}">{{ $cli->nombres }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 col-xxl-6 mb-3">
                        <label>Asginar a</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario">
                                <option>Seleccionar</option>
                                @foreach ($empleados as $emp)
                                    <option value="{{ $emp->id }}">{{ $emp->username }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 col-xxl-6 mb-3">
                        <label>Medio de instalación</label>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <select class="form-control" name="id_tipo_instalacion" id="id_tipo_instalacion" >
                                <option>Seleccionar</option>
                                @foreach ($tipo_instalacion as $etipo)
                                    <option value="{{ $etipo->id_tipo_instalacion }}">{{ $etipo->descripcion }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 col-xxl-6 mb-3">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <div class="input-group" data-placement="bottom" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
                            <input name="id" id="id" class=" form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 col-xxl-6 mb-3">
                        <label>Contraseña</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input name="contraseña" id="contraseña" class=" form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Softwares</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">                       
                        {{-- <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> --}}
                            <table id="example4" class="display min-w850">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">Seleccionar</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">Nombre</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">Softwar</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">Version</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">Marca</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">Tipo de venta</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle" >Observación</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($clientes as $cli)
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle"><!-- This input -->
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="id_software_instalacion[]" value="{{$cli->id}}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">{{ $cli->nombres}}</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">{{ $cli->apellidos}}</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">{{ $cli->pais}}</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">{{ $cli->telefono}}</td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">
                                        <select class="mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="id_tipo_venta[]"  >
                                            <option value="" selected>Tipo de venta...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Key</option>
                                            <option value="2">Instalacion</option>
                                            <option value="3">Key + Instalacion</option>
                                            <option value="3">Viruz</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">                                                                                                
                                        <input name="obs_software[]" class=" form-control" type="text"> 
                                    </td>  
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                            
                        </table>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Observación General</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
        
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar instalacion</button></p>
                        
                    </form>
```

Comment: porque no usas un updateOrCreate? en el modelo revisaste los fillable fields?

Comment: porque busco que en mi tabla software_instalacion se guarden por id del software seleccionado es decir que si seleccion software 1: me tiene que guardar a la par sus datos de lado. Si los fillable estan bien, de alguna forma quisiera separar los datos del table en row y que los datos se guarden por separado pero el id del software sea el indice

Comment: Bueno puedes hacer una peticion ajax para cada vez que seleccionen un checkbox se guarde y cuando lo quiten se elimine

Comment: Muestra algo que hayas intentado. Creo que si un checkbox no está tildado, no se envía con el formulario